# Read a CSV file and store data in JSON form in Django

Tags: json, django, python-3.x, csv

I have a CSV file in media folder inside my django project. I want to read the data from the CSV file and store it in JSON format either directly in the database or convert it into JSON from CSV file and then store it, and enable me to view it on an html page, in my Django Web Application.

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far.

Comment: add some sample data of your csv file !

Comment: `In_Count,Out_Count,Dwell_Time,Time
6,5,4,08:00
19,13,3,09:00
27,19,6,10:00
8,9,7,11:00
0,8,1,12:00
8,10,0.5,13:00
3,5,0.25,14:00`

Comment: @dkb I didn't know how to do it, I was reading but it didn't helped so didn't quite do anything. I just wrote a external python script for reading the data. However, what I want is the data to get saved in the Django models directly without the need of any conversion. The purpose is to create charts using chart.js which accepts data in json form only. So, I am trying to figure out how to do it. If there is any other way to make charts using any javascript library which can work for me, kindly let me know.

Answer (score 0):

as I dont know the data format in your csv file i supposed that you have to element in your csv file ... 
now you can write your csv file in a list of dictionaries. so you can do anything you want to...

```
import pandas as pd
csv = pd.read_csv('./your_file.csv')

dataset = []
for i, (item1, item2) in csv.iterrows(): 
    dataset.append({"item1":item1, "item2":item2})
```

Comment: Thank You for the reply sir, is it possible to directly save this data in my django models directly?  `in_count    = models.PositiveIntegerField()
 out_count   = models.PositiveIntegerField()
 dwell_time  = models.DateTimeField()
 time        = models.TimeField()`

Comment: no problem .. instead of append to the list in the for loop you can save each parameters you want in your Django model.

Comment: Ok Sir. Thanks a lot. However, in your code I have to manually define the name of the csv file, what I want is that for every new csv file which gets generated and stored in my media-storage folder after every 1 hour, is to be read automatically and then the values should be stored.

Comment: your welcome .. actually that is just playing with code .. you can save your csv file in a certain format and change read that  just like that in your code ... if you want not to change it manually you can just  use something like this .. and for each call change the dynamic part of your input csv file    ` pd.read_csv('./your_file.csv_{}'.format(dynamic_part))`